# Dependency injection into onEnter callbacks for state changes with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When using ui-router in Angular JS, what dependencies can be injected into onEnter callbacks? Specifically, I want to use the $http service and a constant defined in the parent module. The code I am working with defines ui-router states in module config; I know I cannot use services in config code, but maybe it's ok to use them in callbacks defined by config code? At any rate, the following code seems to work; I am just worried it may not be reliable. I guess 
the real question is, when are dependencies injected? Does this happen at the time that a function is defined, or at the time that a function is called?

```
angular.module('sim', ['ui-router']).
    constant('ENV', {
        BASE_URL: '/simulation/secure'
    }).
    config(config);

function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('root.training', {
            url: '/training', 
            controller: 'trainingCtrl', 
            onEnter: function($http,ENV)
            {
                $http.get(ENV.BASE_URL + '/setIsRunning');
            }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependencies are injected when the function is called. Looking at the [source code of ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/legacy/src/state.js), the `onEnter`-callback is called during a state transition, when the transition is considering `entering`. The call to the `onEnter`-callback is done using Angulars `$injector.invoke()` function, which resolves any dependencies in the `$injector` and invokes the method, as per the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector). So pretty much any dependency should be valid to use in `onEnter`.